# ¿Cómo organizar las clases de Python?

Tags: python, clase

Es una pregunta filosófica. Como ingeniero uso Python de una forma autodidacta desde hace poco tiempo y me es un estupendo complemento para llegar donde no llegan programas de software profesionales, o donde las típicas hojas de cálculo Excel están muy lejos de dar la talla.

Veo que tiene una filosofía muy modular y un agudizado concepto del reciclaje del código. «¡Estupendo!» pienso, «puedo generar clases con los criterios de las normativas industriales y luego echar mano de ellas en los diferentes programas que cree para resolver casos particulares.»

Mi duda es si organizar estas clases en torno a un directorio general de clases, con lo cual tengo todas las clases organizadas en un mismo espacio. Pero, si con el tiempo tuviera que reorganizar el directorio, mis viejos programas no podrían importar todas las clases, con lo que tendría que actualizar los imports de cada módulo afectado. ¡Vaya follón!

Por otra parte, si dentro de cada proyecto tengo una carpeta para las clases, tengo toda la información de clases necesaria dentro de un mismo directorio y ante una revisión siempre sería más sencillo actualizar los módulos. Pero, por otra parte, ante un nuevo proyecto sería un caos recordar donde está la clase y su última revisión que me interesa reciclar para el nuevo trabajo.

Por eso, insto aquí a los programadores más experimentados a que me arrojen algo de luz de cómo sería la manera más adecuada de gestionar los directorios que contengan las clases, antes de que me arrepienta de cómo lo esté haciendo.

Comment: Lo siento, Pedro, pero este foro no es apropiado para pedir opiniones. Haz mejor tu pregunta en la [lista de python en español](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-es) o en el [foro de telegram](https://telegram.me/PythonEsp) donde estarán (estaremos) encantados de responder todas tus dudas.

Comment: OK, gracias. Seguiré la indicación en próximas cuestiones.

Comment: Si esta pregunta es reformulada, será muy interesante. Creo que @PedroBiel se refiere a como empaquetar un proyecto Python, y reutilizarlo en otros proyectos.

Comment: Sí, por ahí van mis dudas. Actualmente, por carga de trabajo tengo aparcado el tema de Python, por lo que no he podido bien replantear la pregunta, bien buscar otro foro más adecuado para la cuestión.